# SQLite, GROUP BY with RANGE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with the following query:

```
SELECT p.bp_pod, COUNT(j.max) as 'COUNT',
SUM (CASE WHEN j.max <= 120 AND j.min <= 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM (CASE WHEN  j.max > 120 AND j.max < 140 OR j.min > 80 AND j.min < 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM (CASE WHEN  j.max >= 140 OR j.min >= 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT 0 as bp_pod UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as bp_pod UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as bp_pod )
p LEFT JOIN
tb_journal j
ON p.bp_pod = j.bp_pod
GROUP BY p.bp_pod LIMIT 0, 90;
```

But this query groups the records according to `bp_pod` which could have only three values: `0, 1, 2`.

Here is the `table` I am working with

```
CREATE TABLE "table" ( `bp_pod` NUMERIC, `max` NUMERIC, `min` NUMERIC )
```

and here are some values I am working with:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('21', '134', '78');
INSERT INTO table VALUES('13', '126', '88');
INSERT INTO table VALUES('6', '97', '54');
```

Now I changed the app and it can have multiple values, so I need to implement the GROUP BY with ranges, something like:

```
bp_pod > 5 AND bp_pod < 12
bp_pod >= 12 AND bp_pod < 21
bp_pod >= 21 AND bp_pod < 24
```

but include such a range within the index `pod` 0, 1, 2.

The expected result is below here:

```
pod    COUNT   range_1 range_2 range_3
0       0       1        0       0
1       0       0        1       0
2       0       0        0       1
```

Any clue?
Thank you.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], by providing a tailored toy database. Do so by either using the `.dump` feature, or by giving lines of "create table ..." and "insert into  ...".

Comment: @Yunnosch added in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful because of the `left join`.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT p.pod,
       COUNT(j.bp_max) as 'COUNT',
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.max <= 120 AND j.min <= 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.max > 120 AND j.max < 140 OR j.min > 80 AND j.min < 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.max >= 140 OR j.min >= 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT 0 as bp_pod, 5 as minb, 12 as maxb UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 as bp_pod, 12, 21 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as bp_pod, 21, 24
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     tb_journal j
     ON j.bp_pod >= p.minb AND j.bp_pod < p.maxb
GROUP BY p.bp_pod;
```

Comment: It does EXACTLY what I expected, thank you very much!
Just one thing, how could I do to include also in the last 'SELECT 2' in a round way also the interval 24-5?

Comment: @Soul . . . I don't understand your comment.  If you want additional intervals, add them to the `p` subquery.